# Cant Download file with unauthentication with google drive api v3 php

Tags: php, laravel, curl, google-drive-api

i find many resources in google but i still can't solve it.
my code is the same google drive api to download an image but it return this
[download file return metadata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCVIr.png)

and here is my code download

```
 public function download($id)
  {
    $this->initializeToken();
//    $token = \Session::get('token');
//    $this->client->setAccessToken($token);
//    dd($id);
    $response = $this->drive->files->get($id, [
        'alt' => 'media'
    ]);
    $content = $response->getBody()->getContents();


    file_put_contents("blogxxx.png", $data);


  }
```

it return in above image.
and i try with curl.

```
 public function download($id)
  {
    $this->initializeToken();
    $response = $this->drive->files->get($id, [
        'alt' => 'media'
    ]);
    $content = $response->getBody()->getContents();

    $oAuthToken = $token['access_token'];
    $getUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/' . $id . '?alt=media';
    $authHeader = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $oAuthToken ;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $getUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        $authHeader ,
    ]);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
//    dd($data);

    curl_close($ch);

    file_put_contents("blogxxx.png", $data);
  }
```

But i still return as the same result.

I can fix it about 3 days :( . thanks for any helping me.

**SOLVED**
Although nobody helps me, i still solve it with very very simple solution.
You only add a response header and echo the $content in the below:

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"123.png\"");
    echo $content;
```

it work for me after 3 days. yeah :)

Comment: What is the error / problem?

Comment: when i click download file with id and token is supplied. it return this
>�PNG  IHDR��T��tEXtSoftwareAdobe ImageReadyq�e<�oiTXtXML:com.adobe.xmp ��!�8�IDATx�� �%�Y�y�孹o�Y{�j��T�J�%�2Xm�� �mD�vs�1��a��6c�==6g�................

Comment: Have you ever tried opening a PNG file in notepad?  Give it a shot.  That is the string representation of your file.

Comment: i had tried open it but it's not a png file by system. it is a png image.